# ./node_modules/amazon-connect-streams/release/connect-streams.js 332:27

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error with my code:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/amazon-connect-streams/release/connect-streams.js 332:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (332:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|          */
|         class QuickResponses {
>           static isEnabled = function () {
|             const client = connect.isCRM() ? connect.core.getClient() : connect.core.getApiProxyClient();
|             return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
```

does anybody know how to fix this

I've already tried reinstalling everything but it didn't work

Comment: What nodejs version are you using? Instead or reinstalling, try upgrading it!